# Clueless Encryption

Tags: cipher

What method has been used to encode this message?

`I  s Txz KhxIiHM s q nivRs OafToHB hduiTplssz gil s  a q aT mWphl ens di gmVUJbgVzanbm pCleepLsxM smshyao rSgeREq jezknqcVxs s  aNvSEge`

Okay just one clue:

> The message can be decoded, even without knowing the key number in no more than (message length)/2 attempts, using pencil, paper and mathematics no more complex than counting and comparing. No computer knowledge is required.

Comment: If you wan't to ask for more clues do so. I will happily answer yes or no questions.

Comment: OK, I'll delete it. Another question: some of the spaces are actually double spaces. Is this deliberate or just a typo?

Comment: Shouldn't be any typos. The code was generated by code and then checked that it decodes then pasted. Any double spaces are accurate.

Comment: I view this on my iphone.  Is the linebreak between gmVUJbgVzanbm and pCleepLsxM deliberately chosen or simply for formatting on the website?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Just the website. The code doesn't contain any line breaks.

Comment: Should there be a whitespace between gmVUJbgVzanbm and pCleepLsxM though?

Comment: Yes there is a single space character. Using block quote has fiddled with formatting slightly.

Comment: Maybe if I knew anything about cryptography I would be able to use your clues.....

Comment: PS: This puzzle is entirely unsolvable using only the iOS app.  (Heck I haven't been able to solve it with the portion that isn't accessible to the iOS app)

Comment: @Bob I have seen it.  That's why I know it's not solvable on iOS app ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64 Cheers

Comment: @LeppyR64 I have a solution to the iOS app problem.

Comment: @Bob that works

Comment: OK a yes/no question here. Is it a transposition? I.e., do letters retain their value, just in a different order?

Comment: Is this double-space in `... s  a ...` a mistake? I think I'm near to guessing

Comment: Viginere cipher?

Comment: I noticed that there's 28 capital letters and 28 spaces... not sure if that's useful in any way...

Comment: @orp I count 26 spaces?

Comment: "The method applies an identical transformation to each character."  Does this refer to the encoding or decoding process?  And is the transformation independent of the character's position, or is it also independent of the character itself (i.e. is it a linear transformation)?

Comment: ' '26,
B1,
C1,
E2,
H2,
I3,
J1,
K1,
L1,
M2,
N1,
O1,
R2,
S2,
T4,
U1,
V3,
W1,
a6,
b2,
c1,
d2,
e6,
f1,
g5,
h4,
i5,
j1,
k1,
l4,
m4,
n4,
o2,
p4,
q4,
r1,
s12,
u1,
v2,
x4,
y1,
z4

Comment: @2012rcampion: Some of them are double spaces though. I meant there are 28 whitespace characters. Probably not a relevant observation anyway, though.

Comment: It is most likely a permutation of the given string and probably obtained by swapping S[i] and S[i+key].

Comment: @orp My comment still stands; I count 20 single spaces and 3 double spaces for a total of 26.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I got 26 spaces too. I've got a Community Wiki post in the works but I'm waiting on the OK from my question on Meta.

Comment: @Aravind, how would that work.  There's a bunch of boundary conditions.  S[i+key] swapping with S[i+2.key]??  What happens when $i>135-\mathrm{key}$?

Comment: @DrXorile I assumed what he was proposing would involve the indexes wrapping around, but I haven't found anything for which that would work yet anyway.

Comment: I guess that swapping covers the counting part, but what about comparing? It might be that S[i] and S[i+key] gets swapped whenever a certain condition is fulfilled? Of course, that condition could be basically anything.

Comment: Just FYI, since I can't put this in a post: "*If this puzzle had a key if* [sic] *would be 25*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The encoded message is:

> This is a sample message

Explanation:

> The last hint from **question_asker** was my starting point. He quoted a clue which I couldn't find anywhere. I looked at the [revision history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/17437/revisions) of the question and there it was, together with [many more](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/2ba00967-aa59-4283-863a-210ab445accd/view-source). The one which revealed the "encoding" to me was:
> `This puzzle's message starts with the word  This.`
> Lets take a look at the beginning of the encoded text and mark **T** with **1**, **h** with **2**, **i** with **3** and **s** with **4**.
> `I  s Txz KhxIiHM s q nivRs OafToHB hduiTplssz gil s`
> `...4.1....2..3...4....3..4....1....2..31..44...3..4`
> We can see the sequence **1234** near the beginning with some irregular spacing between the letters. The interesting thing is, the same sequence appears a little further to the right with exact the same spacing (ignoring some of the numbers which are just there as fillers). I copied the encoded text to a second line below the first and rotated it so that both sequences are one above other (25 characters to the left). Taking the characters which are equal in both lines reveals the message.
> `I  s Txz KhxIiHM s q nivRs OafToHB hduiTplssz gil s  a q aT mWphl e`
> `s OafToHB hduiTplssz gil s  a q aT mWphl ens di gmVUJbgVzanbm pClee`
> `.....T....h..i...s.. .i..s .a..... ........s.............a..m.p.l.e`
> `ns di gmVUJbgVzanbm pCleepLsxM smshyao rSgeREq jezknqcVxs s  aNvSEge`
> `pLsxM smshyao rSgeREq jezknqcVxs s  aNvSEgeI  s Txz KhxIiHM s q nivR`
> `..... .m...............e.......s.s..a....ge.........................`
> Now most of the other clues make sense as well.

Comment: @question_asker One of the (now deleted) clues says the message starts with the word "This". Therefore I marked the letters in the encoded text. To find the message take a text editor where line wrapping can be disabled, copy the message in 2 lines one above other, and remove 25 chars at the beginning of the 2nd line. Then mark all chars which are equal in both lines.